# Why don't Proximity Prompts work without a character?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm in a pickle. (not literally, of course)

I had a ship game, which used Proximity Prompts to enter the docks. This worked well enough. However, that was for a click to move system, and now I'm attempting to make a direct control system (e.g. you press WASD to move your ship instead of clicking a point on the ocean), and as such, there is *no* character in the game, and have done everything else without a character.

In short: They don't work now and I have no clue why.

The script is *near enough* the exact same on both games (The original game's script has a lot more other functions in it, but nothing that would affect this), and so is the configuration of the  Proximity Prompt. But I don't see how it could be to do with the lack of a player Character, and if it is, how do I edit the default code for it, to work without one? (I had a look, but couldn't find anything useful) As it doesn't seem like it will have direct dependence on the character, as any animations or custom behaviour would have to be done connecting to the `ProximityPromptService`/Prompt itself to add those via the events.

This is literally the whole server-side script I have for it.

```
local proximitypromptservice = game:GetService("ProximityPromptService")

local function get_player_data (player)
... --Unrelated, it's just a function to get player data, no issues here.
end


proximitypromptservice.PromptTriggered:Connect(function(promptobject,player)
    print("Prompt TRIGGERED") --Not seen in the log when the Prompt is pressed.
    if promptobject.Name == "DockControl" then
        print("DOCKCONTROL")
        if player.IsLoading.Value == false then
            game.ReplicatedStorage.Dock.AccessDock:Fire(player,...)
        end

    end

end)
```

It's probably worth noting that when you press the key, e.g. `E`, it does the hold Duration animation and then disappears, and reappears as you'd normally expect. Creating a custom docking system is not out of the question, but I would *really really* prefer not to create an overcomplicated, clunky system for something that should work out of the box.

Any help would be appreciated,
The Frog.

PS: Also tried this on both local and server scripts as a child of the prompt to no avail.

```
script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function()
    print("TRIGGERED")
end)
```

Comment: Proximity prompts require a character. You will likely have to make your own propts with SurfaceGui's instead